# React mapping error when refreshing the page after the first load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping

I am trying to calculate the total price from two different array props. I am using map to render the portfolio array and using the id from it to locate the price from the stock array using findIndex and multiplying it to the quantity located in the portfolio array.

I am able to render the results for the first time. However, when I hit refresh I'm hit with a mapping error. I have an idea to what is causing this error but not sure how to resolve it.

```
profile array = {
name,
portfolio {
   stockId (ref Stocks.id),
   stockName,
   quantity
   }
}

stocks array = {
id,
stockName,
stockPrice
}
```

```
import React from "react";



const MyPortfolio= ({profile, stocks}) => {
   
    const findIndex = (id) => {
        const index = stocks.findIndex(index => index._id === id)
        return stocks[index].stockPrice;
    }
    // console.log(profile)

return (
    <section>
        <h3>{profile.username}</h3>
        <p>{profile.money}</p>
        <p>Portfolio</p>
            <ul>
                {profile.portfolio ? profile.portfolio.map((ownedStock) => (
                    <li key={ownedStock.stockId}>
                    {ownedStock.stockName} <br/>
                    {ownedStock.quantity} <br/>
                    Current Worth: {parseInt(ownedStock.quantity) * parseInt(findIndex(ownedStock.stockId}
                    </li>
                )): null}
            </ul>
    </section>
)
}

export default MyPortfolio;
```

Comment: When you refresh? By doing that you're essentially resetting the app. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Check if profile.portfolio is typeof Array after reloading, I thing the issue is out of this component.

Comment: @Andy that is correct. the data will render perfectly if I enter through the Nav component. But once I'm on the page and manually refresh/reset the page the error will occur.